# Multiple Sticky header with angularjs Plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sticky

I tried to get angular plugin for multiple sticky header. 
I got same using javascript and css , codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/gBrdo

Can you please let me know any angular directive with same functionality. I used ngSticky but it doesnt work with multiple header.

Comment: http://ngmodules.org/modules/sticky-headers

Answer (score 1):

Works great, with no jquery dependencies:

https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSticky

Comment: Angular NgSticky doesn't work with Multiple Sticky, Please advice if you know alternative.